# Is there a way to run functions in the order of a randomly generated list in Arduino IDE?

Tags: c++, list, random, arduino, arduino-ide

I have a list of functions like this for instance:

```
void cube () {…}
void diamond () {…}
void cylinder () {…}
void sphere () {…}
void cone () {…}
```

and I make a random function where it generates a list of non-repeating numbers (let's say between 0 and 4) so that it creates a list like this:

```
random_List = {1,0,4,2,3}
```

I already know how to make the list, but after that, what would I have to do in order to make the functions run according to the sequence of the list? I will assign a number to the functions like `void cube () {}`would be assigned 1 and `void diamond () {}` would be 2 and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Function pointers might help:

```
using func_type = void (*)();

func_type funcs[] = {&cube, &diamond, &cylinder, &sphere, &cone};

for (auto index : random_List) {
    funcs[index]();
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `auto` be sufficient instead of `func_type`?

Comment: I personally would just shuffle the function pointers the same way as originally the indices instead of having two separate lists.

Comment: I am not acquainted with the ```using``` aspect of it, but whatever